# javafx-2, editable ComboBox value set only on enter key

Tags: combobox, javafx-2

I have a javafx editable ComboBox. 
The value property is updated only when i press enter, and not just exiting the ComboBox. 
It seems to me to be a bug and not a design feature because it would be strange that a non focused control shows a value that is not reflected by its value property.

Here is an SSCE that shows the problem:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class T02 extends Application {

public static void main (String [] args) { launch(args); }

@Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("javafx.runtime.version: " + System.getProperties().get("javafx.runtime.version"));

    VBox vbox = new VBox();

    //this combobox is the object of the investigation
    final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
    comboBox.setEditable(true);
    vbox.getChildren().add(comboBox);

    //I need another component just to allow the ComboBox to loose the focus
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    vbox.getChildren().add(textField);

    //And here it is: when comboBox looses focus, i print its state
    comboBox.focusedProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        @Override public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            //return if it has the focus: i am just interested on focus lost
            if (comboBox.focusedProperty().get()) {return;}
            System.out.println(comboBox.getValue());
        }
    } );

    stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
    stage.show();
}

}
```

output:
[write something on combo and click on the other control (or press tab, it's the same)]
null
[click back on the combo, press enter and click down on the text field]
hello

The first null is strange, maybe buggy as I said before. I did a quick search on jira and haven't found this behavior. (Maybe i haven't noticed it)

**update**
Ok, i've just added the

```
System.out.println("javafx.runtime.version: " + System.getProperties().get("javafx.runtime.version"));
```

and get the result:

```
javafx.runtime.version: 2.1.something
```

I've upgraded the version with the last available:

```
javafx.runtime.version: 2.2.3-b05
```

And the issue disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The related bug which was fixed in [RT-21454 ComboBox value should update when focus leaves it](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-21454).

**Update**

AgostinoX reports that the issue is resolved by upgrading to `JavaFX 2.2.3-b05`.

You can check the javafx version you are using by placing the following code inside your JavaFX application's start method.

```
System.out.println("javafx.runtime.version: " + System.getProperties().get("javafx.runtime.version"));
```

Comment: your answer leads me to the solution, maybe you could append an explicit "check your javafx version" suggestion for people reading the question.

Comment: I clarified the answer based on your suggestion and version checking code in your question update.